# ARM Neon - Accumulate dot product to output's index

Tags: c++, arm, neon

I want to achieve vector dot product with the following snippet, where the dot product of vector `a` and `b` can be added to `c` at the first position, so the result will be `[30, 0, 0, 0]`.

```
#include <arm_neon.h>
#include "utils.h"

int main() {
    float a[4]{1, 2, 3, 4};
    float b[4]{1, 2, 3, 4};
    float c[4];

    float32x4_t A = vld1q_f32(a);
    float32x4_t B = vld1q_f32(b);
    float32x4_t C = vmovq_n_f32(0);

    // Computation

    vst1q_f32(c, C);
    print_vector(c, 4);
}
```

Is there a idiomatic way to do this with Neon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
C = vmulq_f32(A, B);

float32x4_t zero = vmovq_n_f32(0);
vst1q_f32(c, zero);
float32x2_t D = vpadd_f32(vget_low_f32(C), vget_high_f32(C));
D = vpadd_f32(D, D);
vst1_lane_f32(c, D, 0);
```

Comment: I wondered how to do the addition and thought it would be complicated.  For integers, the `MLA` gives an instruction count of the same order (ignoring overflow).  It seems like NEON is not too advantaged here?

Comment: @artlessnoise There are dedicated `dot` instructions on `armv8.2`